# Converting raw xml string to exmpp Packet type

Tags: erlang, exmpp

How to convert raw xml string to a tuple(**NewPacket**) that can be sent using function

```
exmpp_session:send_packet(MySession, NewPacket).
```

For example if the following xml string  has to be sent how to convert it to the type that send_packet function accepts. ?

```
<message from=’abc@example.com’
         to=’xyz@example.com’
         type=’chat’>
       <body>
         Good evening.
       </body>
</message>
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: In exmpp_xml.erl file there is a function **document_to_binary** but there is no function to convert other way.

Comment: If you `git clone https://github.com/processone/exmpp.git` you can then use [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) in the `exmpp` source tree to find examples of using `send_packet` or any other function you happen to be using.

Comment: "but there is no function to convert other way" `fun exmpp_xml:parse_document/1`